# Loading in a file multiple times (n) in a row causes my Message Box messages to show up (n) times

Tags: c#, wpf, forms

So this is a really stupid problem, When I load up the same CSV file multiple times into my program this results in a messagebox appearing multiple times (n). The times I've opened a file. I'll post some code here to hopefully see why this is happening.

```
   public partial class Form1 : Form
   {
       [DllImport("shlwapi.dll")]
       public static extern int ColorHLSToRGB(int H, int L, int S);
       public
           bool First = true;
       
       public Form1()
       {
           InitializeComponent();

       }
public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) #button1 is used to start OpenFileDialog
       {
 OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog
           {
               InitialDirectory = @"D:\",
               Title = "Browse Text Files",

               CheckFileExists = true,
               CheckPathExists = true,

               DefaultExt = "csv",
               Filter = "csv files (*.csv)|*.csv",
               FilterIndex = 2,
               RestoreDirectory = true,

               ReadOnlyChecked = true,
               ShowReadOnly = true
           };

           if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
           {
               textBox1.Text = openFileDialog1.FileName;
               PickCount.Clear();
               PickCountProduct.Clear();
               PickCountSchap.Clear();
               LocatieProduct.Clear();
           }


              
               foreach (Control c in Controls) #I have ~400 clickable textboxes which display extra information when clicked. Therefore I store them
               {
                   if (c is TextBox)
                   {
                       textBoxes.Add(c);
                   }
                }

                   foreach (var c in textBoxes)
                   { c.Click += textbox_Click;
}
}
public void textbox_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {
           string location = ((TextBox)sender).Text;
           int pickcount = 0;
           string product = "";
           bool Test3 = PickCountSchap.TryGetValue(location, out int test);
           if (Test3)
           {
               pickcount = test;
           }
           else pickcount = 0;
           bool Test2 = LocatieProduct.TryGetValue(location, out HashSet<string> test2);
           if (Test2)
           {
               foreach (var output in test2)
               {

                   int i = output.IndexOf(" ") + 1;
                   string str = output.Substring(i);
                 //  Console.WriteLine(str);
                   bool Test4 = PickCountProduct.TryGetValue(str, out int test3);
                   if (Test4 == false)
                   {
                    product = product + "\n" + output + " PickCount: onbekend";
                       
                   }
               
                   else product = product + "\n" + output + " PickCount: " + PickCountProduct[str];
               }
           }
           else product = "Geen informatie over producten op deze locatie gevonden";
           if (First)
           {
               MessageBox.Show("Informatie over schap " + location + "\nPickCount: " + pickcount + "\nProducten op deze locatie: " + product);
             
           }
           

       }
```

So I have a button1, which opens a file explorer, from which I choose a .csv file. When I load in multiple files in a row I get the MessageBox from clicking a textbox the amount of times I've loaded in a file. I can't find out why this is happening, so I hope one of you has had this issue before or can see in my code why it is happening.

Kind regards,
DKT

Comment: `First` will always be true, or?

Comment: @KlausGütter yes, I tried to use First as a way to find if I can block all other messageBoxes from showing up, but then I can only click a textbox once before I don't get any messagebox.Shows at all.

Comment: There is more "dead code" in your question: e.g. what do you want to do with the list `textBoxes`? Currently nothing, It would be good to strip down the code to the minimum.

Comment: @KlausGütter, sorry. this is what I do with the textboxes:    foreach (var c in textBoxes)
                   { c.Click += textbox_Click;
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With each button1_Click you add another event handler to the Click event of the text boxes. So when `button1_Click` is executed twice, each click on the text box will invoke `textbox_Click` twice etc.

The solution is to remember if you already added the event handlers and skip this step the second time.